# Slow Insert Performance

Tags: oracle, insert

I have a table that is basically used for auditing purpose with 3 CLOB fields and 13 other fields. We have many indexes created on the table because of which insert performance (using java application) is very very bad.We can't disable the indexes as the inserts happen all the time on the table. Please provide inputs on how best the insert can be optimized. Thanks

Comment: what is the concurency? how many rows do you insert at a time? You have only inserts and no updates? How many reads on the table?

Comment: We have a java application that spawns 50 threads simultaneously to insert records into the table ~ 50 lakh records/day. From the awr I can see enq: HW - contention as the major wait event. The table has 3 LOB columns so I am suspecting BUG Bug 7319120 - HW contention for BasicFile LOBs - special workaround (Doc ID 7319120.8). Please advice if my analysis is right.